# List, str and int help in python

Tags: python, elementtree

I have list of number like this:

146, 168

174, 196

230, 252

258, 280

286, 308

314, 336

342, 364

370, 392

the first number represent value i got from my code(start number) and the second number on the line after comma is end value. What i try to do is use both of start and end value to print the string.
here is part of my code:

```
root = etree.parse(f)

for lcn in root.xpath("/protein/match[@dbname='DB']/lcn"):
    start = lcn.get("start")
    end = lcn.get("end")
    print "%s, %s" % (start, end,)
    if start <= end:
        start = int(start+1)
        print start    
    if start <= end:

      print list(start)

      start = int(start+1)
```

I got the error message saying that i can't concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects.. Side note: on the list index has one alphabet letter in it. So my goal is to print out those letter on one line per each start and end value. For example
ACTGAGCAG and possibly import to another output file. Could you please help me with this?

UPDATE: so everything work out, I got the result but now i want to make them appear on one line. I did this but i got the error message saying that TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable

```
    while start <= end:
        inRange = makeList.append[start]
        start += 1
        print inRange
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```
start = lcn.get("start")
end = lcn.get("end")
```

use

```
start = int(lcn.get("start"))
end = int(lcn.get("end"))
```

This is because `lcn.get` returns a string.

Instead of `start = int(start+1)`, use `start += 1`. You no longer need to convert to an integer and `start += 1` is shorthand for `start = start + 1`.

Instead of `print "%s, %s" % (start, end,)`, use `print "%d, %d" % (start, end)`. The comma at the end is unnecessary and `start` and `end` are now integers so use `%d` instead of `%s`.

UPDATE:

And instead of

```
while start <= end:
    inRange = makeList.append[start]
    start += 1
    print inRange
```

use

```
for i in range(start, end):
    makeList.append(i)
    print(i)
```

if using Python 3 or use

```
for i in xrange(start, end):
    makeList.append(i)
    print i
```

if using Python 2.

Comment: I just did. thanks again. So I got that working but the result came up as one letter per line and i did this..  while 
start <= end:

            inRange = makeList.append[start]
            start += 1
            print inRange